# Doctrine MappingException with message 'The target-entity Entity\\ItemsBags cannot be found in 'Entity\\Players#itemsBag'

Tags: php, doctrine2, backend

Доброго времени суток. Бьюсь уже второй день и не могу понять в чём дело... В рантайме ловлю ошибку:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'The
>   target-entity Entity\ItemsBags cannot be found in
>   'Entity\Players#itemsBag'.' in
>   /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:762
>       Stack trace: 
>       #0./var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php(1028):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::invalidTargetEntityClass('Entity\\ItemsBag...',
>   'Entity\\Players', 'itemsBag')
>       #1./var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(272):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->validateAssociations()
>       #2./var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(251):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->validateRuntimeMetadata(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata),
>   NULL)
>       #3./var/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(332):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadM in
>   /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php
>   on line 762

При проверке доктрины, и апдейте, всё проходит успешно:

> ```
>  root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema:update --force
>  Updating database schema...
>  Database schema updated successfully! "4" queries were executed
> ```

---

> ```
> root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:validate-schema
> [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
> [Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.
> ```

Пробовал очищать кеш, удалять прокси и перегенерировать их, но ничего не дало результатов...

> ```
> root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata
> Clearing ALL Metadata cache entries
> Successfully deleted cache entries.
> root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:query
> Clearing ALL Query cache entries
> Successfully deleted cache entries.
> root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:result
> Clearing ALL Result cache entries
> Successfully deleted cache entries.
> root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-proxies
> Processing entity "Entity\Objects"
> Processing entity "Entity\Weapons"
> Processing entity "Entity\ItemsBags"
> Processing entity "Entity\Players"
> Processing entity "Entity\Translations"
> Processing entity "Entity\Worlds"
> Processing entity "Entity\Tiles"
> Processing entity "Entity\WorldStructures"
>
> Proxy classes generated to "/tmp"
> ```

Players.php:

```
namespace Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="players")
 *
 */
class Players{

    ...

    /**
     * @var ItemsBags
     *
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ItemsBags", mappedBy="player")
     */
    private $itemsBag;

    ...
}
```

ItemsBags.php:

```
namespace Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="item_bags")
 *
 */
class ItemsBags{

    ...

    /**
     * @var Players
     *
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Players", inversedBy="itemsBag")
     * @JoinColumn(name="player_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $player;

    ...

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так я делаю?

Answer (score 0):

В общем выяснил я в чём дело. На самом деле я не добавил секцию autoload в свой composer.json

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "core/" }
  },
```

P.S. Единственное, чего не могу понять, почему до этого момента всё работало, хотя и были у меня энтити уже в проекте...